# Is magento enterprise is available in free?

Tags: magento-enterprise

Is it possible to download Magento Enterprise edition for free? If it can anyone share the link or if it is paid download means where I can get the details. Please share any links for details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Magento Enterprise edition is not free and you can check the Price here :

https://magenable.com.au/magento-ecommerce/magento-enterprise-pricing/

Here you can see in official site  :

https://magento.com/products/enterprise-edition

For Magento 2 :

https://magenable.com.au/magento-ecommerce/magento-2-enterprise-price/

https://www.appseconnect.com/cost-estimation-of-magento-2-0-enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

Magento Enterprise edition is not free.

**Magento 2 Enterprise edition:**

https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Pricing-of-Magento-2-Enterprise-Edition-License/td-p/58519